# React list unique key error. What is wrong?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, vite

What is causing the unique key error?

The code should provide a unique key to each list item.

for example if
`x_values = {'male':[1,2,3], 'female':[2,3,4]}`

the keys should be : 'mean-male', 'median-male', 'mean-female' and 'median-female'

Error message: **Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.**

```
<Grid container>
        {Object.keys(x_values).map((item) => {
          const { mean, median } =
            calculateStatistics(x_values[item]);
          return (
            <Grid item>
              <List>
                <ListItem key={`mean-${item}`}>
                  <ListItemAvatar>
                    <Avatar sx={{ bgcolor: "primary.dark" }}>
                      <LabelImportantIcon sx={{ color: "#c1d4c6" }} />
                    </Avatar>
                  </ListItemAvatar>
                  <ListItemText
                    primary={
                      <Typography>
                        <strong>Mean:</strong> {mean.toFixed(2)}
                      </Typography>
                    }
                  />
                </ListItem>
                <ListItem key={`median-${item}`}>
                  <ListItemAvatar>
                    <Avatar sx={{ bgcolor: "primary.dark" }}>
                      <LabelImportantIcon sx={{ color: "#c1d4c6" }} />
                    </Avatar>
                  </ListItemAvatar>
                  <ListItemText
                    primary={
                      <Typography>
                        <strong>Median:</strong> {median.toFixed(2)}
                      </Typography>
                    }
                  />
                </ListItem>
              </List>
            </Grid>
          );
        })}
      </Grid>
```

Comment: You haven't put the `key` on the element that's actually the child in the list...

Comment: Think "list" as in "a collection of JSX elements", not as in "the `<List>` component".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the key on the first child that is being returned in the array:

This wont make your key unique, you will have to make another way of naming the key.

```
<Grid item key={`mean-${item}`>
              {*/.../*}
            </Grid>
```

Comment: (I might re-name the key, though, since it's no longer the `"mean-"` part, but a container for mean/median ;) *(And thanks for editing out the irrelevant chunk of code )*

Comment: If you are not changing the order of the list, by updating, inserting, moving or deleting items, or refetching data, you can safely use the index of the array as the key.